# Please tell me where to find early versions of thttpd web server

Tags: thttpd

I am going write a simple web server, after read some really simple samples of http servers,

I want to read something complicated, so i went to thttpd server's web page, but I can not find

early versions of thttpd, because i want to read the source code following the Changelogs.

I'm really appreciated if  somebody tell me how to find them  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the download, try asking for it directly. They have a mailing list:

> There's a mailing list: thttpd@mail.acme.com (thttpd-request@mail.acme.com to subscribe, archived [here](http://marc.theaimsgroup.com/?l=thttpd&r=1&w=2))

Comment: @MadFrog Has it helped? Do you have what you needed?

Comment: Thank you @Mifeet I tried to subscribe it, but i just can not complete the subscribation when it came to the email that asks me to change 'REJECT' to 'ACCEPT', always end up with an Error. So I just gave up.

Comment: @MadFrog Seems like their server is down - the link in my answer doesn't work now, but it did when I posted it. Perhaps try later.